# Update DB with numerous checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I have made an inbox style page on my site. Next to each mail I have a checkbox

```
    <input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='$id'>
<button class="btn btn-default" input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="Delete"> <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete Selected</button>
```

Mark as Read

When the user checks a number of emails, i would like them to click a sumbit button and the next page delete all selected emails.

I have the below php code

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                         //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                         //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.
    }
}
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE mail SET mail_deleted='1' WHERE id='$checkbox'") or die(mysql_error());
```

the page display's the mail ID's (EG `312` for ID's 3, 1 and 2 but I'm not sure how to update the DB with these?

Can anyone help?

Thanks

**Update**

I would like to have 2 buttons, one to mark as read and one to mark as deleted
I have the below code which works but how can i add the unread one?

```
 if (isset($_POST['delete_button')) {
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $check_list = $_POST['check_list'];
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE mail SET mail_deleted='1' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $check_list).")") or die(mysql_error());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $check_list = $_POST['check_list'];
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE mail SET mail_deleted='1' WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $check_list).")") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 submit buttons, so I could have one as "Delete" and one as 'Mark Read'?

Comment: Yes..we can keep two submit buttons in one form..each will execute individual for related action like delete or mark read...

Comment: I'm a newbee and not sure how to do this :S

Comment: Use PDO with prepared statements  and transactions instead of `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['checklist']) && count($_POST['checklist'])) {
        $dbh = NULL;
        try { 
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password); // connect to database
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $del = 1;
            $dbh->beginTransaction(); // execute statements in a batch
            foreach ($_POST['checklist'] as $cl) {
                // create a prepared statement and add values to it
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE mail SET mail_deleted = :del WHERE id = :id"); 
                $stmt->bindParam(':del', $del, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $cl, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute(); // queue execution
            }
            $dbh->commit(); // run the batch of statements
            $dbh = NULL; // close connection
        }
        // attempt to recover from failure
        catch (PDOException $PDOex) {
            $dbh->rollback();
            $dbh = NULL;
            echo $PDOex->getMessage();
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            $dbh->rollback();
            $dbh = NULL:
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
        // assuming things went irrecoverably wrong, still close the connection
        finally { $dbh = NULL; }
    }
?>
```